# Unable to fetch graph for IO Service Time in munin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, munin

I am implementing munin on my ec2 ubuntu 10.04  instance  I was not able to fetch graph for IO stats but I figured out the problem and IO stats are working fine. But still I am not able to fetch the graphs for IO service Time, which is one of the very important parameter. Kindly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could occur because of several reasons. Basic steps to debugging plugins are listed on the [munin documentation](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/Debugging_Munin_plugins):

- restart munin-node
- try to run the plugin via `munin-run`
- try to call the plugin via `munin-node`
- observe the munin log files

Comment: Do any errors show up, especially when running the plugin via `munin-run`?

Comment: I am not getting any response when i run munin-run iostat_ios which is IO service metrics.